# ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, alassetslibrary

Since I "upgraded" my project to Swift 3, I get an exception when trying to use the `ALAssetLibrary`. I use this instead of Photos library because I want to write extensive metadata to the photo file and I have not found a way to do this with the Photos library so far.

The following code now fails:

```
let usingBlock = {
    (group: ALAssetsGroup?, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in
    // Code to execute
} as! ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock
```

It seems that the cast fails. I need an object of type `ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock` in order to call `ALAssetsLibrary.enumerateGroupsWithTypes`.

Again I know this is deprecated, but it should still work somehow shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The signature of ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock has changed to 

`typealias ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock = (ALAssetsGroup?, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>?) -> Void`

You need to make the stop argument an optional and then it should work (see [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/assetslibrary/alassetslibrarygroupsenumerationresultsblock)